# Cordova IOS Plugin installation

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am pretty new to Cordova and iOS (and MAC). I have everything set up and using Visual studio + Networked Mac. Everything is working, I can build and deploy to Simulator and device.

But when I tried to install a plugin "statusbar", I am getting this build error

```
"Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error 404 Not
Found: cordova-plugin-statusbar: {1}"
```

I have installed it in the config.xml, but for some reason when building it is not finding the plugin. Do I need to install it on the mac too or should it be deployed with the rest?

Tried installing the plugin from the Mac terminal into the VS project folder on windows, but same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: which cordova version are you using? you are using the plugin id, that is only supported by the latest version (cordova 5), not sure if visual studio already supports that version. try installing like this cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar

Comment: @jcesarmobile , is it enough to only install it on windows, or do I need to install it on the Mac aswell? On windows I have Cordova 5.1.1

Comment: installing it on windows should add it for iOS if you added iOS platform

Comment: @jcesarmobile  , got it working now. Added iOS in cordova and got it working. Thanks :)